# symfony + doctrine help

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine

I am looking for some, I have the following table setup in my test symfony site,

```
event  
----------  
id
title
description
date

event_signup  
--------------
id
name
event_id
```

From this I hope you can see that there is a relationship between event and event_signup.

I want to know how I can get the names for the people that have signed to an event, with mysql I would do something similar too,

`SELECT('*') FROM event LEFT JOIN 'event_signup' ON event.id = event_signup.event_id`

How could I write in the styl of Doctrine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have defined the relationships correctly in your schema file, you would be able to first retrieve the event object you want, then just write `$event->getEventSignups()` to get the related objects, and call `->getName()` on them to get the names.

Answer (score 1):

Go [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/03)

It looks like this

```
JobeetAffiliate:
  actAs: { Timestampable: ~ }
  columns:
  url:       { type: string(255), notnull: true }
  email:     { type: string(255), notnull: true, unique: true }
  token:     { type: string(255), notnull: true }
  is_active: { type: boolean, notnull: true, default: 0 }
   relations:
   JobeetCategories:
    class: JobeetCategory
    refClass: JobeetCategoryAffiliate
    local: affiliate_id
    foreign: category_id
    foreignAlias: JobeetAffiliates
```